# C#/UWP Efficient way to show pictures from zip in a ListView

Tags: c#, image, win-universal-app

I have a ListView where I want to show about 700 pictrues from a zip file.
My ListView ItemSource is a ObservarableCollection which contains the entry names for the files in zip and I hava a ValueConverter for converting these strings to bitmaps for the Image View inside my List:

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {

        var entry = (value as string);

        if (archive == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(entry))
        {
            var errorImageuri = new System.Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/error_image.jpg");
            return new BitmapImage(errorImageuri);
        }

        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
        archive.GetEntry(entry).Open().CopyTo(memStream); // archive is a static ZipArchive
        memStream.Position = 0;

        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
        image.SetSource(memStream.AsRandomAccessStream());

        return image;
    }
```

My problem is, the code works fine on Desktop, but causes Outofmemory on Phones (700 items seem to be a bit too much).
Does anyone can think of a more efficient way of showing a List with images from a zip.

Comment: why not just unzip it to local storage?

Comment: Unzipping it takes a lot of time, too

Comment: Okay, the problem seems to be the Hoizontal Scrolling, it works just fine with my above code if it is a "normal listview". Can be closed